# How to pevent formulas to change when I cut and paste the referenced cells?

Tags: excel-formula

I have J column validating if the contents on the B and E columns are the same so I can make some adjustments in the sheet, as in the picture below

[image]

J column formula is = =IF(E663=B663;"si";"CAMBIAR"), and it allows me to identify where I have to move the content one cell below, because I needed to update the values in the sheet. When the value is CAMBIAR (CHANGE IN ENGLISH) I select all the cells in the columns D and E and cut them and paste them one row below.

At that moment the formulas in J column change to =IF(E665=B664;"si";"CAMBIAR"). Note the rows are not the same anymore, B is stuck in the last row. I expect both to be 665. I have to refresh the formulas each time making this work tedious. How can I prevent excel to make that change? I tried using absolute formulas with the $ sign on both cell references but excel doesn't car and changes it anyway.

Comment: The question is NOT about programming, this question belongs to http://superuser.com

Comment: you can cut and then paste not the cell itself, but THE VALUE of the cell. nter the cell for editing and cut the text from there. Or do cut/paste in the "formula bar" above the workjbook grid.

Comment: @Arioch'The it has been decided that formulas, especially complex uses of the formulas, are on topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use INDEX to fix it:

```
=IF(INDEX($1:$1048576;ROW($XFD663);5)=INDEX($1:$1048576;ROW($XFD663);2);"si";"CAMBIAR")
```

There is a draw back to this method.  Since we are referring to the entire sheet, any change on the sheet will cause all of the formulas to recalculate.  It may slow down the performance depending on how many formulas one has.

Comment: It's true it took a while loading the formula and the fill down, but once that was done, it refreshes in a snap. Thank you. I'll invite you a drink If I could.